# how to read data from the screen through a transparent window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window, transparent

Hi iam making a bot to game, and i have a little problem

this is my transparency class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CzytnikHeal extends JFrame {
private static final int width = 45;
private static final int height = 15;

    public CzytnikHeal(){
        setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(230, 255, 0, 32));     

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

i want to read from monitor any details by using this transparency window. Any suggestions how to do it?

specifying i want move this transparency window to e.g hp in game and read this by my program to working bot and i dont know how to read this information from screen :d

Comment: For starters, I think that Java would be the last language that I'd choose to do a task like this, and instead, I'd pick a language that allowed me to get closer to the OS, such as C# if for a Windows application.

Comment: why? I saw bots doing something like that and they were done in java

Comment: Really, in Java using the Swing library? If so, then my bet is that they are using JNI or JNA or some other external library, since Java was built from the ground up to be as OS-agnostic as possible, meaning the code does not bring you close to the metal or the OS, two things that would make doing things like this easier. Please show the code that you have "seen" that does this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gmp3qFVQiCM